# Hiding an element when I click outside of it or somewhere else on the page

Tags: jquery, hide

Ok, I have a list of radio buttons inside a DIV, this DIV slides down when I click on span.

Now, when I select one of the radio buttons, the text in the span is replaced and the DIV slides back up.

I also need to make the DIV with the list of radio buttons slide back up whenever the user clicks somewhere outside of it/any other place on the page.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {       
    $('.selected-search-wjs').text($(this).parent().text());//This replaces the text/selection
    $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp('fast');//This makes the DIV slide back up after a selection has been made
});
```

Any idea how to that?

Thanks in advance.

PS. Let me know if you need the HTML. I didn't put it here because I don't think is necessary since this is a behavior feature regardless of how the HTML is put together. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's the solution for this.**

All I needed to do was to create another function using the *.mouseleave* method:

```
$('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).slideUp();
});
```

Now, I was using *.mouseout* but it didn't work because the container DIV had child elements in it, so once you hover over them the DIV would slide back up.

So I found this simple explanation about why and how to solve it:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/problems-with-jquery-mouseover-mouseout.html

Thanks.

**EDIT--**

I ran into other issues with this case, see the problem and solution here: [Hide element if displayed (a little complex case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674111/hide-element-if-displayed-a-little-complex-case)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var wrapper = $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs'); // cache the wrapper element for speed
$(document).click(function(e) { // when any click is received
    if (
        (wrapper[0] != e.target) && // the target element is not the wrapper
        (!wrapper.has(e.target).length) // and the wrapper does not contain the target element
    ) {
        wrapper.slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply lonesomeday. Please read my reply in "jqueryrocks" post.

Comment: Hey, this didn't work for me. I had to change (!wrapper.has(e.target)) to (!wrapper.has(e.target).length) and then it worked.

Comment: +1 This is a general answer that works with every container that you want to apply something to when you click outside of it. It also the most compatible an reliable solution imho.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's :not selecter, as in

```
$('body:not(.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs, input[type=radio])').click(function() {
    $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Comment: Well, none of the solutions you provided worked. But let's say then that I want to hide/slide up the '.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs' after 3-5 seconds after it's been opened, use some kind of timer then? Thanks for your help.