# Hide element if displayed (a little complex case)

Tags: jquery

I have a list of radio buttons that are inside a DIV called "radio-btns-wrapper-wjs", this DIV slides down/up when you click on a 'trigger' element, in my case a < span > with the class "selected-search-wjs".

The DIV "radio-btns-wrapper-wjs" slides back up when the user selects one of the radio buttons.

This DIV also slides back up when the user does not take any action (does not select a radio button) but **has already moved his mouse over** "radio-btns-wrapper-wjs" DIV and then moves it out.

So far, so good.

What I need is to have the same DIV, "radio-btns-wrapper-wjs", slide back up when the user moves his mouse out from the < span > "selected-search-wjs" element **but NOT if the user moves his mouse over the DIV "radio-btns-wrapper-wjs"**.

The thing is that is that if do this:

```
$('.selected-search-wjs').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp();
});
```

The DIV with the radio buttons, "radio-btns-wrapper-wjs", slides back up as soon as I leave that DIV to select a radio button.

I need a condition that says something like:

*"Hide the DIV "radio-btns-wrapper-wjs" if the user hovers over you and then hovers out. Also, hide this same DIV if the user moves his mouse away from the < span > "selected-search-wjs", but NOT if he moves his mouse over the DIV "radio-btns-wrapper-wjs"."*

Does all this make sense?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="radio-btns-wjs"><span class="selected-search-wjs">&nbsp;</span>
  <div class="radio-btns-wrapper-wjs">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb" value="all" id="all">
      All</label>        
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb" value="ln" id="ln">
      Option 1</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb" value="prodsandserv" id="prodsandserv">
      Option 2</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb" value="publications" id="publications">
      Option 3</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb" value="comm" id="comm">
      Option 4</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="rb" value="lweb" id="lweb">
      Option 5</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
//This slides up/down the DIV with the radio buttons
$('.selected-search').addClass('selected-search-wjs').removeClass('selected-search').append('Please Select&hellip;').click(function() {
    $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideToggle('fast');       
}); 

//This hides the DIV with the radio buttons, if the user has hovered over it
$('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
});
```

As you can see I'm very new to jQuery, but this is way over my head now.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/t2HkQ/3/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you place the mouseleave event on the class="radio-btns-wjs" div, instead of the inner div? That way the mouse can be over the span, or the inner div, but if it leaves the div containing those, the mouseleave event will fire and slide the inner div back up.

**EDIT:**

Here is the change made by Ricardo:

```
//Hide list when mouse leaves the list
$('.radio-btns-wjs').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp();
});
```

There was always a div containing the span that is acting as a button, and the slide out div with it's class property set to radio-btns-wjs. The mouseleave property is moved from the inner div to the containing div (radio-btns-wjs).

Comment: Yep! Your solution worked just fine Harry, I just needed to adjust the position of the DIV containing the radio buttons to 'touch' the < span > since I was leaving a 1px gap between them so the DIV was sliding back up. I liked your solution better because it's a little more HTML efficient than Rionmonster's, yet Rionmonster's solution worked just as well. Thanks a lot! See a demo with the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/t2HkQ/6/

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll add your update to my answer. I'm sorry I didn't code into it, I was walking out the door and didn't have time to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working demo of what you need : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t2HkQ/5/)

**HTML:** (just added a wrapper for the button / menu area)

```
<div id="dropdown" style="height: 140px; width: 160px;">
    //All other HTML here
</div>
```

**jQuery:** (simply hides the necessary drop-down if the mouse leaves the wrapped area)

```
    $('#dropdown').mouseleave(function()
    {
          $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp('fast');       
    });
```

Comment: Rionmonster, your solution worked perfectly. The only down side I had was the extra markup. It was just a matter of targeting the correct HTML element. Thanks a lot for your help and the demo. I gave you a vote, of course.

Answer (score 1):

So, what I did in your demo was to delete this entry:

```
$('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
```

And add this one (because what you really want, in simpler terms is "to slideup when the mouse leaves the wrapper"):

```
$('.radio-btns-wjs').mouseleave(function() {   
  $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp();
});
```

But it didn't work, and I was wondering why, because it had to work... So I looked at your css and found something strange (showing the relevant part only):

```
div.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs {
             position:absolute;
             left:0; top:33px; z-index:10;
         }
```

So finally, what I did was to update your CSS also:

```
div.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs {
             position:relative;
             left:0; top:0px; z-index:10;
         }
```

And voila! It worked =)

**Edit:**

In short, no need for extra HTML

Comment: Correct Francisco, although the fix in the CSS was to modify the top: attribute from 33px to 31px, not 0 though. As I said in my reply to Harry's solution above, there was a 1px gap that was making the sliding DIV slide back up, since they're 'touching' now, it doesn't slide back up unless you move your mouse away. Gracias a lot for your help as well. Gave you a vote.

Comment: Exactly. The problem was that they weren't touching. That's why I changed position: absolute to position: relative. It's better that way because you can put top: 1px leaving that 1 pixel gap between the button and the rest, just like it were before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into your JS:

```
$('.selected-search-wjs').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp();
});
```